# SwiftUI Switching between views

Tags: swiftui

I have a parent view (Content View) containing an array of integers,

The view switcher function inside the parent switches the child view depending on the value of the integer in the array.

The issue I have is is that 'view1' is re-presented (after being presented before) the view is not redrawn and the text in the textfield remains populated.

How can I redraw the child view each time the switch function is called?

thanks

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var views =  [2,1,1]
    @State var currentView = 0

    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            viewSwitcher()
        }
    }

    func viewSwitcher() -> AnyView {
        switch views[currentView] {
        case 1:
            return AnyView(view1(currentView: self.$currentView))
        case 2:
            return AnyView(view2(currentView: self.$currentView))
        default:
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }
}


struct view1:View {

    @State var textInput: String = ""
    @Binding var currentView: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            Text("View 1")

            TextField("Enter Text", text: self.$textInput)

            Button(action: {
                self.currentView += 1
            }){
                Text("Submit")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct view2:View {

    @Binding var currentView: Int

    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            Text("View 2")
            Button(action: {
                self.currentView += 1
            }){
                Text("Submit")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible solution. Using .id modifier makes view unique per-update, so rebuilds.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
func viewSwitcher() -> AnyView {
    switch views[currentView] {
    case 1:
        return AnyView(view1(currentView: self.$currentView).id(UUID()))
    case 2:
        return AnyView(view2(currentView: self.$currentView).id(UUID()))
    default:
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}
```